# Bad performance when SQL Server reuses cached query plan on larger company

Tags: sql-server

I have created a query to retrieve sales information for a particular account, and also a non clustered index for performance.

Most of the time, the query and index works fine. Unfortunately, it's not performing when I execute the query in a company with small amount of sales data, then follow by a larger company.

It is because the query optimizer decided to use clustered index directly instead of the designed non clustered index, as it's more efficient when the company having less data.

The problem occur when the same query got execute on larger company, SQL reuse the generated query plan from the smaller company, which cause slowness on the larger company.

Is there any better option instead of using Index hint/ covering index?

**Some details:**

Sales table:

```
| Company | RunningNumber | Account | SalesAmount | Status|
```

- Clustered index is on `Company, RunningNumber`
- I also have a non-clustered index on `Account, Company`

Query

```
SELECT SUM(SalesAmount) 
FROM SalesTable 
WHERE Company = @P1 AND Account = @P2
```

Comment: Include account into clustered index, after company?

Comment: Look into [option (recompile)](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/using-the-option-recompile-option-for-a-statement/)

Comment: The non-clustered index on `(Account, Division)` isn't a covering index for your query because it doesn't include all of the required columns. At best it could use `Account` for filtering, but will still need to access the table's rows to lookup `Company` and `SalesAmount`.

Comment: Please share both query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also add the full table and index definitions to your question. The best index here is likely to be `(Company, Account) INCLUDE (SalesAmount)`

Comment: Also, although `option (recompile)` can be a good idea, it comes at a cost of constant recompilation. An alternative is to *safely* inject `@P1` directly into the query, this means you get a single plan compiled once per `Company`

Comment: Your "sales table" does not contain a column named Division. It is a bit unusual that your table has no date-related column either. So let us stop guessing; post DDL for the tables involved in your query as well as the requested execution plans.

Comment: Sorry, the non clustered index key should be "Account, Company". I can't share the query plan because of security reason.

Yes, include SalesAmount would be the covering index, but it means we need to include more and more columns into it. That's why i ask for alternative.

Plan per company would be similar to always recompile, as there's not a lot of users logging into the same company.